# Piecewise function of countable continuous functions still continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $I_n=[a_n,b_n]$ with $a_n<b_n=a_{n+1}$ and suppose that $f_n:I_n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ . Consider then $F:[a,b]:= \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} I_n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by
$$
F(t)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty f_k(t)1_{I_k}(t).
$$

Is $F$ then continuous on $[a,b]$?

I think the answer is yes but I am not sure how to prove it. Showing uniform convergence seems not feasible... Intuitively it seems to be true since we are "gluing it together". But is there a nice, short proof of it?

Comment: You have $F(b_n-)=f_n(b_n)$, $F(b_n+)=f_{n+1}(b_n)$, and $F(b_n)=f_n(b_n)+f_{n+1}(b_n)$ so I guess you need equality between these three values. (There is no real “infinite” summation here because pointwisely the summands are zero except for at most two indices.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a condition. We need to have that $f_n(b_n) = f_{n+1}(b_n)$, or else there will be jump discontinuities at the endpoints of the intervals. Let's assume that this condition holds.

Now, to check continuity at a point $x$, it suffices to consider $F$ restricted to a small open neighborhood of $x$. Without loss of generality, assume $x \in I_n$. Then we must consider the cases that $x$ is one of the endpoints of $I_n$, or is in the interior of $I_n$.

If $x$ is in the interior of $I_n$, then we can choose $\varepsilon >0$ small enough that $(x - \varepsilon, x + \varepsilon) \subset I_n$. Restricted to this neighborhood (call it $U$), $1_{I_k}(t)$ is constantly zero for all $k \neq n$. So we have that
$$ F|_U(t) = f_n(t) + \sum_{k\neq n} f_k(t) \cdot 0 = f_n(t) $$

Since we assumed $f_n$ is continuous, it follows that $F$ is continuous at $x$ as well.

The case where $x$ is an endpoint of the interval is similar, but in this case we will end up with two nonzero terms. This is where we'll use the assumption that $f_n(b_n) = f_{n+1}(b_n)$. See if you can work it out yourself.

**Edit:** I just realized that your definition of $F$ will cause a problem at the endpoints. The way it's defined, we have $$F(b_n) = f_n(b_n) + f_{n+1}(b_n)$$ because $b_n \in I_n \cap I_{n+1}$. The only way for $F$ to be continuous is if $f_n(a_n) = f_n(b_n) = 0$ for all $n$ (except $f_1(a_1)$ which isn't being "glued" to any other function). To fix this, I would recommend replacing $1_{I_n}$ with $1_{[a_n, b_n)}$, so we don't end up adding $f_n$ and $f_{n+1}$ at the endpoint. This will actually glue the functions together rather than adding them at this point.

Comment: Yes you are right I was missing that - and this makes perfect sense, thank you!